# can vps be made as secure as having two dedicated server computers?

Tags: webserver

Which is a better option security wise :
                    1) cheaper option - vps (Iam assuming that if one particular virtual server is hacked,then still other virtual servers on that comp will be safe)

2) make diff. dedcted database server (but it can be hacked too afterall,right?)

3)OR  ... make 2 diff. servers on same computer listning to diff. ports!(will dis be called the shared server condition)

Did i correctly assume about vps and dedctd servers ??? and the 3rd case ? please clear my doubts and suggest a solution for my situation!

Comment: Please format your question with proper punctuation. We do not demand correct English, but we like to see at least an effort :)

Comment: Yes, please do make your poster clearer. I would also say VM is going to be your best bet. Even if the instance is compromised it would take specific mal-ware  to access the box.

Comment: Agreed with Lucas here. StackExchange has high standards in terms of question and answer quality. Proper spelling and punctuation isn't *required*, especially for non-native speakers, but questions which show no effort (e.g. usin txtspk like dis lol its rly hrd 2 undrstnd) will simply be downvoted or deleted. Please have a read through the [FAQ](http://security.stackexchange.com/faq) and [How to Ask](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

The problem with VPS is that it will be dependent on the security of the host and the technology used. For instance if a VPS gets hacked on a server using VMWare there will be no known attacks to break through to the hypervisor. Howver with LXC there have been some attacks where it was possible to break out of the jail (both technologies are very different).

Segregation of services is very good, not just only for security but also for availability and scaling. This provided that the credentials for the (administrative) users are different on both machines.

How exactly is your 3 differentiating from your 1?